# LINEAR SEARCH : warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

Tags: c++, linear-search

linear.cpp: In function 'int linearSearch(int*, int, int)':
linear.cpp:15:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
15 | }
| ^

Could you tell me what's wrong with this and why we get this error? and how do we solve it??

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int linearSearch(int arr[], int n, int x) {

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    
        if (arr[i] == x){
            return i;
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    //arr[] = {}
    //x = element to be found = say 4
    // Output = Index of x

    int n;
    int arr[n];
    cout << "Enter n i.e. number of elements in the array" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter array" << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        cin >> arr[j];
    }

    int x;
    cout << "Enter the key or the element to be found" << endl;
    cin >> x;

    cout << linearSearch(arr, n, x) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: At the end of the function, put `throw "oops";`

Comment: What will the function return if its given `n` argument is zero (or less)?

Comment: That loop is worthless. It will never advance to a second (or more) iterations. Look at that code and walk through the first iteration. If `(arr[i] == x)` is true, you're going to return `i`. Otherwise, you're going to return `-1`. Either way, you're leaving the function before ever making it to another iteration. [Talk to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: Also, lineraSearch is equivalent to `return arr[0] == x ? 0 : -1`

Comment: What will happen for: `linearSearch(arr, 0, 0)`?

Comment: `int n; int arr[n];` in `main` isn't doing you any favors either. (a) That isn't standard C++, which doesn't support variable-length native arrays, and (b) even if you're using some non-standard toolchain extensions that do support VLAs, that thing doesn't magically resize when you change `n` later in the program. Whatever book/site is teaching this, burn it. Then learn how to use a `std::vector`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your implementation is completely wrong. Second of all, return an integer at the end. Updated code:

```
int linearSearch(int arr[], int n, int x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {   
        if (arr[i] == x){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, use `std::find(arr, arr+n, x) - arr`.

Comment: I tried that first, it says "exited with code=3221225725" when I do that

Comment: Your error is in main: `int n; int arr[n];` This is wrong at two different levels. Use a `std::vector`.

Comment: You can strengthen this answer dramatically by expanding on *First of all, your implementation is completely wrong*, and it won't take much work.

Comment: @KrissCross C++ doesn't work like a spreadsheet. Once something happens, it stays happened unless you do it again. If you calculate a value and later change one of the variables used as an input to that calculation, the previously computed result does not change to match the variable's new value. If you request an array of size `n`, it's always and forever going to stay at the size specified by the value of `n` when the array was created. If `n` has not been given a value, there's no way to know how big the array will be.